# Recording of multiple Breakout games from a Gymnasium Vectorized Environment

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, atari-2600

I want to record the interaction with a vectorized environment of two games of Atari's Breakout using `Gymnasium`.
Unfortunately, when executed, my code only records the last game of the vector during an episode
(or maybe it internally overwrites recordings until the last recording).
I am looking for a solution to record all games of a vector for each episode.
Here is my current code:

```py
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium.wrappers.record_video import RecordVideo

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from IPython.display import display, Video

wrap_record_video=lambda x: RecordVideo(x,
                  video_folder="recordings/",
                  name_prefix="breakout_test",
                  episode_trigger=lambda x: True,
                  disable_logger=True)


env = gym.make_vec('Breakout-v4', 
                   render_mode='rgb_array', 
                   num_envs=2, 
                   vectorization_mode="async", 
                   wrappers=[wrap_record_video])

d = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
d.start()

for episode in range(0, 5):
  state = env.reset()
  done = False
  score = 0

  while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample() 
    n_state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    done = True in terminated or True in truncated
    score += reward

  print("Episode:{} Score:{}".format(episode, score))
  display(Video("recordings/breakout_test-episode-{}.mp4".format(episode), embed=True))

env.close()
d.stop()
```

I have seen examples that wrap the vectorized environment into a `VecFrameStack` environment of
`stable-baselines3`. However, `VecFrameStack` requires the vector to be of class `stable_baselines3.common.vec_env.VecEnv`,
while the output of `gym.make_vec` is of class `gymnasium.vector.VectorEnv`.